# How to compare values from 2 arrays and return true if all conditions are true

Tags: php, arrays

I have 10 students ID's with each `sub1` and `sub2` that defines which subjects they are enrolled in, in the `$result` array variable below

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [sub1] => BIO [sub2] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [sub1] => BIO [sub2] => ) 
[2] => Array ( [sub1] => MATH [sub2] =>CHEM ) 
[3] => Array ( [sub1] => MATH [sub2] => BIO ) 
[4] => Array ( [sub1] => PHY [sub2] => ) 
[5] => Array ( [sub1] => ELCT [sub2] => ) 
[6] => Array ( [sub1] => SOC [sub2] => GEO) 
[7] => Array ( [sub1] => HIS [sub2] => ) 
[8] => Array ( [sub1] => ART [sub2] => BIO ) 
[9] => Array ( [sub1] => PHY [sub2] => HIS ) 
)
```

and another `$subjects` variable containing the subject that each student should be enrolled in

```
 Array ( 
    [student1sub] => BIO 
    [student2sub] => MATH 
    [student3sub] => CHEM 
    [student4sub] => PHYS
    [student5sub] => ELCT 
    [student6sub] => ECO 
    [student7sub] => SOC 
    [student8sub] => GEO 
    [student9sub] => HIS 
    [student10sub] => ART 
    )
```

I need to check if each student is enrolled in a the according subject that he should be enrolled in from the condition in `$subjects` by checking their `sub1` and `sub2` in the `$result` array

I read that I should use `in_array` but not sure how to implement it to loop over each student `sub1` and `sub2`

```
if (in_array("BIO", $subject))
  {
    return true;
  }
else
  {
    return false;
  }
```

if all 10 students from `$result` meet its conditions then I need to show a success msg if not show an error msg

**what i am trying to achieve | expected output**

find the sub from `[student1sub]` in `[0] => Array ( [sub1] => BIO [sub2] => )`

find the sub from `[student2sub]` in `[1] => Array ( [sub1] => BIO [sub2] => )`

find the sub from `[student3sub]` in `[2] => Array ( [sub1] => MATH [sub2] =>CHEM )`

find the sub from `[student4sub]` in `[3] => Array ( [sub1] => MATH [sub2] => BIO )`

find the sub from `[student5sub]` in `[4] => Array ( [sub1] => PHY [sub2] => )`

find the sub from `[student6sub]` in `[5] => Array ( [sub1] => ELCT [sub2] => )`

find the sub from `[student7sub]` in `[6] => Array ( [sub1] => SOC [sub2] => GEO)`

find the sub from `[student8sub]` in `[7] => Array ( [sub1] => HIS [sub2] => )`

find the sub from `[student9sub]` in `[8] => Array ( [sub1] => ART [sub2] => BIO )`

find the sub from `[student10sub]` in `[9] => Array ( [sub1] => PHY [sub2] => HIS )`

Comment: is this in a function?

Comment: what is final expected outocme you want? can you post that too in your question?

Comment: not really, its just after my arrays

Comment: @AlivetoDie just a success if all conditions are met or error msg if not

Comment: @DanielWill  i am asking is do you want to compare `[student1sub]` with the first one only which is `[0] => Array ( [sub1] => BIO [sub2] => )` or in the whole array?

Comment: When you ask a question you should supply actual code, not output from print_r. It would also be helpful if you supplied your expected result, not just some totally unrelated code. It's impossible to give you a good answer based on what you've provided, and your description is too vague.

Comment: @AlivetoDie the first one only, so `[student1sub]` to  `[0] => Array ( [sub1] => BIO [sub2] => )` , `[student2sub]` to  `[1] => Array ( [sub1] => BIO [sub2] => )`  and so on

Comment: @BrianGottier you are right, i thought i did, i will update it with the expected outcome my bad

Comment: @BrianGottier edited can you vote it up pls, so people view my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to check that the requirements have been met by each enrolled student, so:

```
// In the future, it would be helpful if you provide an array like this in the question:
$enrolled_student = array(
  array('sub1' => 'BIO'),
  array('sub1' => 'BIO', 'sub2' => 'CHEM'),
  array('sub1' => 'MATH'),
  array('sub1' => 'PHY', 'sub2' => 'GEO'),
  array('sub1' => 'ART'),
  array('sub1' => 'ELCT', 'sub2' => 'HIS')
);

// In the future, it would be helpful if you would provide an array like this in the question
$required = array(
  'student1sub' => 'BIO',
  'student2sub' => 'BIO',
  'student3sub' => 'BIO',
  'student4sub' => 'BIO',
  'student5sub' => 'BIO',
  'student6sub' => 'BIO'
);

$all_confirmed = TRUE;

$i = 0;
foreach( $required as $r )
{
  if( in_array( $r, $enrolled_student[$i] ) )
  {
    // The requirement has been met
  }
  else
  {
    // The requirement has not been met
    $all_confirmed = FALSE;
  }
  $i++;
}

echo $all_confirmed ? 'All confirmed' : 'Not all confirmed';
```

Comment: how can i confirm that they were all met ? should i add another condition in the if statement ?

Comment: I see other problems with what you are doing though. For instance, you are checking if a requirement has been met, but what if there is more than one requirement for a student? Maybe you have handled that somewhere else.

Comment: there is only one requirements per student

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood what you were trying to do. If so this might help you.

```
$result=array (
         array('sub1' => 'BIO' ,'sub2' =>''),
        array( 'sub1' => 'BIO' ,'sub2' =>'' ),
        array( 'sub1' => 'MATH', 'sub2' =>'CHEM' ),
        array( 'sub1' => 'MATH', 'sub2' => 'BIO' ),
        array( 'sub1' => 'PHY' ,'sub2' =>'' ),
        array( 'sub1' => 'ELCT', 'sub2' =>'' ),
        array( 'sub1' => 'SOC' ,'sub2' => 'GEO'),
        array( 'sub1' => 'HIS' ,'sub2' =>'' ),
        array( 'sub1' => 'ART' ,'sub2' => 'BIO' ),
        array( 'sub1' => 'PHY' ,'sub2' => 'HIS' ),
        );
$subjects=array(
                'student1sub' => 'BIO',
                'student2sub' => 'MATH',
                'student3sub' => 'CHEM',
                'student4sub' => 'PHYS',
                'student5sub' => 'ELCT',
                'student6sub' => 'ECO',
                'student7sub' => 'SOC',
                'student8sub' => 'GEO',
                'student9sub' => 'HIS',
                'student10sub' => 'ART'
                );      
        $i=0;
        $test=true;
        //bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack , bool $strict = FALSE  )
        foreach ($subjects as $val){
            echo "\n student ".($i+1)." is studying ".$result[$i]["sub1"]." and ".$result[$i]["sub2"]." he should be studying ".$val;
            if (!in_array($val,$result[$i])){               
                $test=false;
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        if ($test)
            echo "\n success";
        else 
            echo "\n error";
```